# Is this function continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(1+xy^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}, &\text{if }(x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
\\1, &\text{if }(x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}
$$

Is this function continuous? How do I figure this out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take $\ln$ and think about the first-order Taylor polynomial of $\ln u$ at $u=1$.

Comment: Hint: What happens if $x<-\frac{1}{y^2}$?

Comment: @Zen: Are you alleging that this happens near $(0,0)$?

Comment: Ted, I tried and didn't figure out your meaning. Can I say that y=x+1 as x->1 and then solve the limit for f(x,x+1)?

Comment: sam: the question would involve the limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Oh sorry! Got confused with another excercise.

Comment: @TedShifrin: No, but he simply asked if the function was continuous, and while the point in the domain he was interested in was probably (0,0), I was pointing out that he must not forget the rest of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider $$0 \le \left |\log\left((1+xy^2)^{\frac 1 {x^2+y^2}}\right)\right|=\left|\frac {\log(1+xy^2)}{ x^2+y^2}\right|\sim \left|\frac {xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac {|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2} \le |x| \to 0$$ as $x\to 0, y\to 0$.
This implies the continuity of the function under consideration at $(0,0).$